# What happens if I exceed the limits of Heroku Add On free-tier

Tags: heroku

I'm relatively new to Heroku. I need to integrate my app with elasticsearch by using one of the add ons provided, such as Searchbox.

The free tier for searchbox has a storage limit of 5mb.

If I exceed this limit will I be charged automatically for my usage or will it just cap itself and ask me to either change to a paid tier or delete some stuff.

I don't want to be charged unnecessarily for just a development instance.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will just cap itself. In order for Heroku to charge you, you have to explicitly change to a paid tier.